# When asking: Should I explain my reasoning so far?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In [Are all product topologies/spaces over real numbers Euclidean spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925343/are-all-product-spaces-over-real-numbers-euclidean-spaces) I asked the "simple" question whether all product spaces (not inner product space) over real numbers are Euclidean spaces. One could (possibly) answer this just by looking at the title of the question.

However, after I detailed where I am coming from and how I got to the specific (sub-) question on whether a dot product is induced by every product space over the reals, the question got long.

Should I detail my questions like that or just keep to the bare minimum?

Comment: Why was *this* question downvoted?

Comment: Follow up with the answerers who took time to answer your question.  And provide any clarification they seek, and ask about anything you don't understand in a comment below the answers.  math.meta.se is not intended to counsel every user who asks or answers a question on main, and comes here for specific advice.  Also see the math.se chatroom "Constructive Feedback".

Comment: And to answer your title question, YES, explain your reasoning so far, and show any work you've done based on that reasoning.